# Editing a third party question, review, history

Tags: support, editing

I tried to contribute to the site by editing a third party question:

[Difference between 類推する and 推測する](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/43286/difference-between-%E9%A1%9E%E6%8E%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-and-%E6%8E%A8%E6%B8%AC%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)

I added hurigana and a couple of minor changes (ga to wo, and moving bold to previous line)

（[文脈]{ぶん・みゃく}から意味を）　[推測]{すい・そく}する・[類推]{るい・すい}する

After editing, I added a description of the action, and posted.  A message appeared stating the edit would be saved to a queue for processing (and review?).

Either the change did not appear, or it appeared and disappeared.  I am interested to know what happened.

- If two edits overlap can one be cancelled out?  (I would guess there
  is a locking mechanism to prevent that, but maybe not.)
- If an edit
  is accepted or rejected, is there any notification?

Update:  I figured out how to see the history by clicking the "last edited" area to the left of the posters icon.  My edit is not included in the history.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your edits ([1](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/11748), [2](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/11749)) were rejected by myself (in both cases) and by one other reviewer (for the first edit).

Generally speaking, an edit should make substantial improvements to the post and not invalidate existing answers.

Your first edit was mainly about adding *furigana*. We usually discourage such edits, because they may be more disruptive than helpful.  See

- [Adding Furigana to other people's articles](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/550/1628)
- [Can I edit a post to replace Hiragana by Kanji?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1654/1628)

Your second answer tried to incorporate information given in an answer into the question, invalidating the part of the answer that addressed this issue. This is also discouraged, although as a rule of thumb, I think it is fine to suggest edits to incorporate information given in *comments* (before they are addressed in an answer).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer with the valuable information.